# List 'Except' comparison - ignore case

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, case-sensitive

I have two lists and I want to compare them and get the differences, while ignoring any case differences.

I have used the following code to get the differences between the two lists but it does not ignore case differences.

```
IEnumerable<string> diff = list1.Except(list2);
List<string> differenceList = diff.ToList<string>();
```

I tried this:

```
IEnumerable<string> diff = list1.Except(list2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

but Except does not seem to be having a string case check of that sort (so error). I'm hoping there's a work around.

Comment: That should probably be a `StringComparer`, not `StringComparison`. Pay attention to the types...

Comment: See the [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb336390.aspx) overload with an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms132151.aspx). As @JeffMercado said, there can already several `IEqualityComparer<string>` be found under [StringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx)

Comment: Thanks all :) I can't believe I didn't try `StringComparer`.

Comment: @SuperJohn - Then put it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's what worked:

```
IEnumerable<string> differenceQuery = inputTable.Except(strArrList,
                                                        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Used `StringComparer` instead of `StringComparison`.

Answer (score 49):

Try this :)

```
List<string> except = list1.Except(list2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

Worked for me!

Comment: Thank you @joebilly for adding that leading space : )

Comment: Thanks @joebilly

Answer (score -1):

use StringComparer as shown below

**Code:**

```
list3 = list1.Except(list2,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```